# How to segment license plate characters removing unwanted characters using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm using opencv python to segment license plate characters and remove unnecessary characters.I want to compare the the height of each character and remove the characters that are below a certain threshold value. can anyone of you recommend me a method to do so? i already tried finding the area using contours but was not successful.this is a sample of the license plate i'm using.

[image]

Comment: what is the so called 'threshold' you are setting? Which letters do want to remove? Be more specific. Looking at your image area of contours seems to be the best option.

Comment: want to remove all the small characters icons and the dash sign from the image and then segment the rest in to separate characters. already tried using contours but it didn't work properly.

Comment: you are overcomplicating things. license plates are standardized, the characters will always be at the same position. you don't need to judge them by size because you know apriori where each character will be.

Answer (score 1):

"already tried using contours but it didn't work properly", this is what you said. But I performed the following using contour operations.

I first resized your image to make it appear bigger (doubled the size).

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=2, fy=2)
```

[image]

I then found all the contours present in the image:

```
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 127, 255, 1)
_, contours , _= cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, 1)

cnt = contours
for i in range(len(contours)):

    #---- Mark contours above certain area ----
    if (cv2.contourArea(cnt[i]) > 1500):
        final_image = cv2.drawContours(img, cnt[i], -1, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow('Marked image', final_image )
```

This is what I got:

[image]